# Getting error --- Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have written a stored procedure to insert in a table  in oracle using hibernate in spring.When I call the procedure from hibernate the data inserted but i got the below error

```
Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_ITEM_TYPE(
   ITEM_TYPE_ID IN number ,
   TYPE_NAME         IN VARCHAR2 ,
    BN_NAME      IN VARCHAR2 ,
    CREATED_BY   IN NUMBER ,
    CREATED_ON   IN DATE ,
    UPDATED_BY   IN NUMBER ,
    UPDATED_ON   IN DATE ,
    IS_DELETED   IN NUMBER  )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO pg_item_type 
    (
      ITEM_TYPE_ID,
      ITEM_TYPE_NAME,
      BN_ITEM_TYPE_NAME,
      CREATED_BY,
      CREATED_ON,
      UPDATED_BY,
      UPDATED_ON,
      IS_DELETED
    )
    VALUES 

    (
    ITEM_TYPE_ID,
    TYPE_NAME,
    BN_NAME,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_ON,
    UPDATED_BY,
    UPDATED_ON,
    IS_DELETED
    );


    commit;
END INSERT_ITEM_TYPE;
```

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PG_ITEM_TYPE")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "insertyItemType",
    query = "CALL     INSERT_ITEM_TYPE(:id,:name,:bnName,:cretedBy,:createdOn,:updatedBy,:updatedOn,:isDeletd)",
    resultClass = GdItemType.class
    )
})

public class GdItemType {
.....
}
```

** DAO **

```
    @Override
        public void saveGdItemType(GdItemType gdItemType) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            //session.saveOrUpdate(gdItemType);
            Query query =  session.getNamedQuery("insertyItemType")
                    .setParameter("id", gdItemType.getItemTypeId())
                    .setParameter("name", gdItemType.getItemTypeName())
                    .setParameter("bnName", gdItemType.getBnItemTypeName())
                    .setParameter("cretedBy", gdItemType.getCreatedBy())
                    .setParameter("createdOn", gdItemType.getCreatedOn())
                    .setParameter("updatedBy", gdItemType.getUpdatedBy())
                    .setParameter("updatedOn", gdItemType.getUpdatedOn() )
                    .setParameter("isDeletd", gdItemType.getIsDeleted());
                    query.list();


        }
```

I stuck here.Can any one help me please....

Answer (score 1):

```
query.list()
```

wants to return the query results as a List. Your procedure does not have any "out"-parameters, so the query doesn't return results to put in a list. Hence the error.

Comment: Can you please provide the correct format of the procedure & if any changes required in dao or model class too.@Robin Topper

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun If your procedure just needs to put data in the database, there is nothing wrong with it. Unlike me, you should know what your program needs to do, and should be in a better position to correct it (if necessary).